# MySQL sounds like query to Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm pretty new to Hibernate, Is there a way that I can convert the following MySQL query to HQL or a Criteria query:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemname SOUNDS LIKE 'some name'
```

If not, are there any workarounds to get a similar functionality implemented using Hibernate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [mysql doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like) :

> expr1 SOUNDS LIKE expr2
>
> This is the same as SOUNDEX(expr1) = SOUNDEX(expr2)

And `soundex`seems supported by [MySQLDialect](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.java.html). So doing something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE soundex(itemname) = soundex('some name')
```

or in HQL

```
Query q = session.createQuery
   ("from items  e where soundex(e.itemname)  =  soundex('%some name%') ");
```

should work.

Comment: This works as well, and I believe this will be a better solution than writing it in SQL

Answer (score 4):

You can use [native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-cud). In your case, simply :

```
sess.createSQLQuery
    ("SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemname SOUNDS LIKE 'some name'").list();
```